# How to upload an image (taken using webcam in a web application) into SQLite database, using Javascript and Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, file-upload

So I am capturing an image of the user from an html page using webcamjs, and i want to store this image data in an SQLite database, using Javascript. Also I am running this on a localhost:3000 server (nodejs rest API) to which this page has to send the the image data as a POST request.

This is the code of the html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>How to capture picture from webcam with Webcam.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
    #my_camera{
        width: 320px;
        height: 240px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/signupdetail" method="POST">
    
    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()" name="faceimg">
    
    <div id="results"></div>

    <!-- Webcam.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/webcam.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    </script>
    
    <!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function take_snapshot() {
            
            // take snapshot and get image data
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                // display results in page
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                    '<img src="'+data_uri+'" id = "faces" />';
            } );
        }
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ajax to post the `data_uri` to server using  fetch() interface

Comment: Simple way: store the image on a server and store the link to the image in the sqlite, fetch and show the image from the url.

If you want to store the image in the sqlite database you will need to convert the image to a byte array and store said array to the database. To retrieve the image you will have to convert the byte array to a bitmap.

Comment: Actually saving is not the issue, as I have not reached the saving stage, I'm stuck at transferring the image data from browser to nodejs server

Comment: I don't know how to use ajax, so if someone could elaborate please